# Is `Map()` when used in a `data.table` parallel? - R

Tags: r, data.table, furrr

From the `data.table` package [website](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/index.html), given that:

> "many common operations are internally parallelized to use multiple CPU threads"

- I would like to know if that is the case when `Map()` is used within a `data.table`?

The reason for asking is because I have noticed that comparing the same operation on a large dataset (`cor.test(x, y)` with `x = .SD` and `y` being a single column of the dataset), the one using `Map()` performs quicker than when `furrr::fututre_map2()` is used.

Comment: `future::future_map2` incurs the overhead of transferring data between processes; if the data is large, then this is a not-insignificant amount of time (with respect to computation time) and can impact the user-time doing something. To answer your question, `Map` is not parallelized.

Comment: @r2evans Many thanks, I thought it was due to the overhead, but just wanted to make sure I wasn't making an oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rather explorative approach and see whether the time elapsed shrinks when more threads are used.
Note that on my machine the maximum number of usable threads is just one, so no difference is possible

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table::data.table(a = 1:3,
                             b = 4:6)
dt
#>    a b
#> 1: 1 4
#> 2: 2 5
#> 3: 3 6

data.table::getDTthreads()
#> [1] 1

# No Prallelisation ----------------------------------
data.table::setDTthreads(1)
system.time({
  
  dt[, lapply(.SD,
              function(x) {
                Sys.sleep(2)
                x}
  )
  ]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.009   0.001   4.017

# Parallel -------------------------------------------
# use multiple threads
data.table::setDTthreads(2)
data.table::getDTthreads()
#> [1] 1

# if parallel, elapsed should be below 4
system.time({
  
  dt[, lapply(.SD,
              function(x) {
                Sys.sleep(2)
                x}
  )
  ]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.001   0.000   4.007

# Map -----------------------------------------------
# if parallel, elapsed should be below 4
system.time({
  
  dt[, Map(f = function(x, y) {
    Sys.sleep(2)
    x},
    .SD,
    1:2
    
  )
  ]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.002   0.000   4.005
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really useful approach and I will definitely use it to interrogate my work going forward. I only have 2 physical cores to test, so could not fully explore time gain (if any) thoroughly.

Comment: I'll "accept" the answer to close the question. Explicit answer is in the comment by @r2evans of the original post.